# How can I find a list of application names in a text without having to search for them manually?

Tags: excel, search, ms-word, find

I have a simple problem that I can't solve. I have two text files containing some application names and I would like to be able to match the first file (the first version) and the second file (the latest version) to see which names are left and which are not. I tried with some online text search programs but the problem is that the names are in no particular order and so if you don't find it in the same place in the second file it gives it as "not found". the files look like this:

```
MyNameApp2
FirstProjet223
HelpMe
ecc...
```

I have a list of about 300 values ​​to match, how can I do it without having to search one by one with the classic "ctrl + f"? Thanks to everyone for any possible help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save each list as a word doc.
Then just compare them and analyse results.

[image]

[image]